# Is it ok for Magento 2 to have 35k categories and 300k products

Tags: magento2, catalog, performance, migration, category-tree

I'm going to migrate a website to Magento 2 that have 35k entities that really close to categories functionality. So I'm wondering is there any issue to have such amount categories? Is there any problem places should be kept in mind? Also, there are 300k products, but they would be simple and shouldn't be a problem, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project currently in development, but after migration, I can assume there are no real problems exists with performance. The only place I've faced the issue it is loading category tree not a case anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 can handle a large volume of data. You can go ahead but make sure your server performance is good to handle such .

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/performance-toolkit/